# object play.http.HttpEntity.Streamed is not a value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Using Scala and Play 2.5.10 (according to plugin.sbt) I have this code:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import play.api.libs.streams.Streams
import play.http._

val source = Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(enumerator))
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, None, Some("application/zip")))
```

The imports there are mostly from testing because no matter what I try I can't get the framework to accept HttpEntity.Streamed. With this setup the error is what the title says. Or taken from the console:

[image: Error]

Looking at the documentation here I can't really figure out why it doesn't work: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.10/api/java/play/http/HttpEntity.Streamed.html

This is also what the official examples use: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream

Does anyone at least have some pointers on where to start looking? I've never used Scala or Play before so any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should import this one

```
import play.api.http.HttpEntity
import play.api.libs.streams.Streams

 val entity: HttpEntity = HttpEntity.Streamed(fileContent, None, None)
 Result(ResponseHeader(200), entity).as(MemeFoRTheFile)
```

It means that HttpEntity.Streamed is not a value so you should wrap it in a Result() with its ResponseHeader and its extension

Comment: It's seems like it was only the "import play.api.http.HttpEntity" that was missing. 

Not sure why the .api is there when I look at the docs though.

Comment: The `play.api.xxx` is for the scala api. `play.xxx` is (mostly) for the java api.